# formula for nth derivative in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am playing with the **sympy** for a while. I want sympy to derive me a formula of nth derivative for specific function.
I tried:

```py
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x')
n = sp.Symbol('n',integer=True)
f = x**n
dnf = f.diff((x,n)) # n times derivative
dnf
# Derivative(x**n, (x, n))
# apply do it
dnf.doit() # still Derivative(x**n, (x, n))
```

Is it possible to get `sp.factorial(n)` as it should be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any object that has a known formula for the nth derivative can define `_eval_derivative_n_times` to return the known value. You are asking about a power (which is a Pow object), so that routine might look something like this:

```py
def ndiff(self, s, n):
    b, e = self.args
    c, b = b.as_coeff_Mul()
    if b == s:
        from sympy.core.relational import is_gt
        if is_gt(e, S.Zero) and is_gt(n, e):
            return S.Zero
        if n == e:
            from sympy import factorial
            return c*factorial(n)
        if (e - n).is_Integer and n.is_nonnegative:
            from sympy import ff
            return ff(e, n)*s**(e - n)*c
    if n.is_Integer:
        return super()._eval_derivative_n_times(s, n)
```

Then tell `Pow` that that is the routine to use:

```py
>>> from sympy import Pow
>>> Pow._eval_derivative_n_times = ndiff
```

And you should be ready to go with some common known results

```py
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> (2*x**10).diff((x, 2))
180*x**8
>>> (x**y).diff((x,y))
factorial(y)
>>> (x**y).diff((x,y-1))
Derivative(x**y, (x, y - 1))
>>> (x**(y+1)).diff((x,y))
Derivative(x**(y + 1), (x, y))
>>> y = var('y', nonnegative=True)
>>> (x**(y+1)).diff((x,y))
x*FallingFactorial(y + 1, y)
```

Note that the routine just returns None if it doesn't know what to do; this will create an unevaluated derivative.